# where's the option of change default email template of forgot password?

Tags: magento2, email-templates

i have created my own new template for forget email notification from option marketing->communications->email templates , i am trying to find from where i can set my email template as chosen template for sending email to user in dashboard . i would be so thankful if anyone can quick respond me option from where i can set it , Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this from: 
**Stores -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Password Options**

**Forgot Email Template :** select template from dropdown.

Comment: Congo brother !!! thanks for saving my time now i can play 8 ball pool :D